# Lock Screen is showing Junk Characters

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-note-3

Intermittently, my lock screen will start to display junk characters. A power cycle will clear up the problem but I'd like to know how to keep this from happening again.

[image]
[image]

The first time it happened in the afternoon and the second time happened overnight so there's no commonality in usage or behavior or updates that I can see.

Update: I've just tried to change it back to the default font and now it's showing up in my notification bar all over the home screen.

Comment: Are you running custom software like CyanogenMod or are you running an app that modifies your lockscreen?

Comment: Nope, I'm running an out-of-box from Verizon phone. It's not even unlocked or in Dev Mode.

Comment: Interesting! It may be extreme, but it'd be interesting to see if it continued after a factory reset.

Comment: Seems an issue from official update, many reports about the same case: [1](http://forums.digitalspy.co.uk/showthread.php?t=2068760), [2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5/help/rogers-s5-lollipop-lock-screen-block-t3095088), [3](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-5-0-lollipop/517452-samsung-galaxy-s4-lock-screen-pin-number-keys-turning-into-white-boxes-help.html), [4](http://topusefulsolutions.com/587711/samsung-s4-s5-lock-screen-numbers-turn-into-white-blocks), [5](http://www.androidpit.com/galaxy-s4-lollipop-problems-and-how-to-fix-them?c=1702163#comment1702163).

Comment: (cont'd) but no confirmation from Samsung yet. I'd say to wait for some time until Samsung aware and fix this issue.

Comment: If this wasn't my first post, I would vote you guys up but unfortunately I have no rep yet. +1 to you guys.

Comment: What software are you using to manage the fonts on your phone?

Comment: Built in OS Functions: Settings -> Display ->  Font -> Font Style

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to restart to fix it :( not a good answer but I've been having the same issue. It was definitely after upgrading to lolipop. It may come back, usually during charging.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I only just discovered a workaround better than reboot today.  Reboot certainly works, but I hate to do it every 2-3 days.

If you are rooted, you can correct these funny characters on your lock screen by resetting systemui without reboot.  There is an app on the Play Store called "Reset System UI".

Alternatively, if you are a Tasker user, do as follows to automate this process.
Create a task by going to
Code -> Run Shell -> under command type in "killall com.android.systemui" without the quotes of course and then check use root.

Then it's up to you to create a trigger to exercise this task at a time and situation least intrusive but also frequent enough so that you don't see these funny characters again.

Good luck!